# Small python 3 script to fetch urls from given website

Tags: python, url, fetch

I like to get certain links from a website written in python 3. I have tried to write it myself but I failed (being a beginner).

I would like the script to do just the following:

1. Ask me for an url (i. e. https://familysearch.org/search/image/index?owc=Q69L-N6T%3A116559001%2C116559002%2C116559003%3Fcc%3D1601210).
2. Ask me for keywords (case-insensitive, but space-sensitive!), like "matrimonios 2000", to fetch corresponding links of the given website.
3. Fetch all urls with "matrimonios 2000" in link name (in this example
   it would be 27 urls named "Matrimonios 2000 vol 1" until
       "Matrimonios 2000 vol 14").
4. Save corresponding urls line by line in a file named "urls.txt" in
   the same folder where the script is running.

This is my code so far:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import urllib2
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

url = input('Please, enter url: ')
try:
    keyword = string(input('Type keyword(s): '))
except ValueError:
    print('You must enter a string value.')

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
urls = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('keyword')
for url in urls:
    print url.get_attribute("href")

file = open('urls.txt', 'w')
f.write(url)
f.close()
```

Comment: For a moment, I was thinking to add my code. My attempts already failed in point 2. So I do not know, whether it is of any use.

Comment: The point of SO is to help you fix errors that occur in your code, not write it for you.

Comment: Is the presented code ok?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general answer would be this:

```
url = 'https://familysearch.org/search/image/index?owc=Q69L-N6T%3A116559001%2C116559002%2C116559003%3Fcc%3D1601210'
keyword = 'matrimonios 2000'

html = requests.get(url).content
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
for link in soup.select('a'):
  text = link.getText().lower()
  if keyword in text:
    print link['href']
```

This would list all the URLs in links in a normal HTML file in a case-insensitive but space sensitive way.

HOWEVER, if you're trying to parse the site listed, they use AJAX to load the actual content.  The url you linked doesn't actually the data you're looking for.  That page just does a POST request to `https://familysearch.org/search/filmdatainfo`, with the payload:

```
{"type":"browse-data","args":{"waypointURL":"/recapi/waypoints/Q69L-N6T:116559001,116559002,116559003?cc=1601210","state":{"owc":"Q69L-N6T:116559001,116559002,116559003?cc=1601210","imageOrFilmUrl":"/search/image/index","viewMode":"i","selectedImageIndex":-1,"openWaypointContext":"/recapi/waypoints/Q69L-N6T:116559001,116559002,116559003?cc=1601210"},"locale":"en"}}
```

Which returns a JSON document which you could parse.  They appear to try to prevent you from doing this, so easiest to use Chrome's "Copy as cURL" function to get this:

```
curl 'https://familysearch.org/search/filmdatainfo' -H 'Origin: https://familysearch.org' -H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br' -H 'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8' -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.96 Safari/537.36' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -H 'accept: application/json' -H 'Referer: https://familysearch.org/search/image/index?owc=Q69L-N6T%3A116559001%2C116559002%2C116559003%3Fcc%3D1601210' -H 'Cookie: fssessionid=USYS45D0C1B6E2A42A66B9E4C9F1D0935D2F_idses-prod05.a.fsglobal.net; fs_experiments=u%3D-anon-%2Ca%3Dshared-ui%2Cs%3D23d64fb841c59b75c0737db6b5dd47d0%2Cv%3D11111011110000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001011000%2Cb%3D49%26a%3Dsearch%2Cs%3D47d3688c3fc1adc06dc151194bb6e298%2Cv%3D110000001011001110100%2Cb%3D50; fs-tf=1' -H 'Connection: keep-alive' --data-binary '{"type":"browse-data","args":{"waypointURL":"/recapi/waypoints/Q69L-N6T:116559001,116559002,116559003?cc=1601210","state":{"owc":"Q69L-N6T:116559001,116559002,116559003?cc=1601210","imageOrFilmUrl":"/search/image/index","viewMode":"i","selectedImageIndex":-1,"openWaypointContext":"/recapi/waypoints/Q69L-N6T:116559001,116559002,116559003?cc=1601210"},"locale":"en"}}' --compressed
```

Which you can pipe to a file, then load with:

```
import json
with open('data.json') as f:
  x = json.load(f)
```

`x` will be a dictionary with a key `containers` which is a list of dicts with all the urls and titles, each looking like this:

```
{"url":"https://www.familysearch.org/recapi/waypoints/Q69G-SJC:116559001,116559002,116559003,122762601?cc=1601210","title":"Matrimonios 1879-1888"}
```

Which you can loop over at your leisure.

Comment: Thank you very much, keredson, for your efforts. Very much appreciated. Would you be so kind as to bring it together to a script, as I am a novice, I would probably still have problems to make a running script. As for AJAX, would it be possible to retrieve an url from `{"url":"https://www.familysearch.org/recapi/waypoints/Q69G-SJC:116559001,116559002,116559003,122762601?cc=1601210","title":"Matrimonios 1879-1888"}` to `https://familysearch.org/ark:/61903/3:1:S3HY-D15Q-CL8` or how would you go about with the json file to get the final urls?

Comment: I'm sorry, I was intentionally avoiding just giving you a script specific for the one site you're trying to scrape.  For me that's crossing the line from "helping educate" (which is what I poke around on SO for) and "custom software development" (which is my livelihood).  But I promise, all the information you need to write that script is here in this answer.

Comment: Thank you, keredson. I will try my best to put your didactic efforts to a working script. :)

Comment: nice use of didactic in a sentence.  =P  thanks for the accept!